# Unable to update AMD GPU driver

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, gpu

Can anyone tell me or want to speculate on why installing graphics card driver updates is so retardedly, stupidly hard to do. I swear I'm almost sure I've NEVER installed graphics card updates without having to research why it's not just installing for at least 2 to 3 hours or just finally giving up. I mean I've been using computers since the beginning you know the IBM compatibles. I had one of the first Pentium 60's remember the ones with the flaw in it. And I have a lot of skill with computers. Hardware, Software and Internet technologies and yet...

We don't have DMA conflicts or IRQ conflicts anymore, any other piece of software or drivers you want to update you just say update or download the new drivers or version and it just installs. Just like that. And then there's GPU drivers and software... I'm not even going to get into it.

And I'm not talking entry level hardware here either. I don't buy top of the line GPUs simply because they would be completely wasted on me since I don't play ANY games and I don't use them for anything but running lots of screens which really doesn't take a lot of processing power just lots of connectors. But I buy reasonably powerful GPUs just because it just wouldn't be right to put entry level GPUs in my LOADED machines.

I am however interested in updating the drivers on my other machine since I discovered quite by accident since I almost never bother to update my GPU drivers since it's such a pain but did so and discovered much to my delight it allowed me to increase the resolution on all my 27" screens from 1920x1080 to 2560x1440. I'm tickled this is even possible I didn't think it was possible to increase the resolution past the "native resolution" of an LCD screen. Now I want to do it on my other machine but the AMD installer has been stuck at 2% for the last 3 hours. Like I said completely retarded. I've got the latest Windows updates installed and most of my other stuff is current as well just not the GPU drivers. Even this machine it has 3 GPUs in it (2 AMD GPUs & an NVIDIA GPU and neither of them fully installed their respective updates however they installed enough that the ability to increase the resolution on their connected screens was included in the updated components. Yay. lol

Help Me.

Thanks in advance.

This is so unreal. I just can't believe a component as major at the GPU can be sooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo hard to install. It's just completely retarded. It's been 5 hours now of uninstalling and retrying, uninstalling and retrying, uninstalling and retrying I've tried a couple of different uninstallers now the AMD one and the DDU recommended by you Photonboy. But nothing lets the driver or even the Catalyst Control Center install. I just can't understand it. How can it possibly be this hard. I mean how can both these companies be THIS BAD at writing software and drivers for their products that they can't just install themselves. clear out whatever's blocking them and insert themselves where they need to be. They need to hire some hackers obviously none of their legitimate programmers have any idea how to write code. lol. I Just don't get it. And this isn't just me that's having issues. There are huge numbers of folks out there that are asking for help for this exact issue for MANY different cards. It's Unbelievable.

btw I'm really trying to be more humorous than anything I'm really not mad or anything I just think it's silly it's such a chore to install GPU updates when everything else these days installs pretty simply. And this has happened most times I've installed GPU updates and I can see from google that I'm definitely not the only one and this goes back for MANY years.

So, More information Sorry as I said I'm relatively new at this.

Windows 7 Ultimate x64
Gigabyte Radeon HD 7870 OC GHz Edition 2GB 256 Bit GDDR5 PCIe 3.1x16

There's actually nothing in the Display Adapters section of Device Manager I've uninstalled all GPU drivers and software from the machine.

I realize my previous version drivers are out of date Tetsujin as I mentioned I really don't typically update my GPU software since I don't use them for anything very demanding on a modern GPU. The 7870 is only a couple years old and while that may be ancient in the world of gaming it still functions perfectly so there's really no reason for me to replace it since it wouldn't mean anything to me to put a newer card in my machine.
Thanks for responding guys.

oh btw Vesselin you're probably right about it being the configuration of my machine I've got 194 apps installed on that machine and that's just the ones that put an entry in "Programs & Features" so it's possible some other app that doesn't play well with GPU software is causing an issue BUT my other machine which is virtually identical just with a different CPU and all different hardware actually but just newer, the software side is almost identical I mean with all the apps installed. And it has 2 AMD Gigabyte 7870s (Same cards) in there and an NVIDIA GTX 660
and the update installed Mostly without much fuss even with cards from both major manufacturers represented running together.

Comment: Please provide more information, for starters: OS Version: GPU Model: Driver version: Device Manager section of your Display Adapters: --- No offense intended, but... I don't know what causes your struggles, but you are going off to extremes. The statistical probability of these 'bad things' always happening to you is abysmal so I suppose the issue may lie in yourself and/or the configuration.

Comment: AMD no longer make the Catalyst drivers, they are legacied - I presume your graphics card is too... but as this is all rant & zero detail, we won't know until you have edited your question to give us some actual information. We are here to help you with your computer problems; your frustration levels are all your own.

Comment: lol you're so right Tetsujin. I typically not that way AT ALL believe me. It is frustrating to me though there's no reason this shouldn't be working. I've uninstalled ALL Graphics drivers and software from the machine and the drivers still won't install.

Comment: Smile. I don't blame you for thinking that Vesselin I know you don't know me. I'm actually VERY SKILLED when it comes to PCs and usually just research and fix issues myself it's only recently I've started trying to actually ASK for help in forums. It's impressive that complete strangers such as yourselves are willing to help people they never met and never will. It shows the best of human nature. But I guess that's what it's been like since the beginning of PCs. People working together and discovering what they can do with these new PC devices. SO MUCH more amazing then when things started.

Comment: The 7870 will accept the newer Crimson drivers, btw. I'd try removing all drivers, from control panel & cleanup in Device Manager. Shut down, remove all but **one** AMD card. Boot & install for that one card, then test both work. Repeat for the NVidia as the sole card.